# iOS UIImageView disappears after rotation M_PI_4

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, rotation, uibarbuttonitem

What is basically happening here is that I'm adding a custom view to the UIBarButtonItem, and I need to rotate it by 45deg , the rotation works perfectly if rotated by 90deg or 180 , but when it's less that 90 the object gets deformed , and on 45deg the object disappears.
Here are the snippets for the button and animation.

```
UIImageView * menuImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"]];
menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuImage];
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenuView:)];
[menuImage addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
[menuImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[menuImage.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[menuImage.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(ShadowSizeWidth, ShadowSizeHeight)];
[menuImage.layer setShadowOpacity:ShadowOpacity];
[menuImage.layer setShadowRadius:ShadowRadius];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:menuButton];
```

The Rotation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationRotateButtonDuration delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_4);

    UIBarButtonItem * currentItem =  menuButton;

    currentItem.customView.transform = myTransform;

}completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
```

Comment: I'm also trying to rotate a bar button item's custom view and running into the same thing. Other views rotate by M_PI_4 just fine, so I'm wondering if it's something to do with UIBarButtonItem (?).

Comment: UIBarButtonItem takes a custom view as background, now the trick that made this work , is that The custom view I chose was a UIImageView which had another UIImageView as child ,I had to rotate this second UIImageView to make this work. I think it's related to UIBarButtonItem yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use anchorPoint and import  `"QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"`

```
currentItem.customView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);//it is not fixed point you have to change.
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't seem to work , will work for M_PI_2 with point(1.0,0.0) , (0.5,0.5) , (0.0,0.0).. but doesn't for M_PI_4 the image will disappear.

Comment: Try these points (0.4, 0.1),(0.8, 0.3) and you have to change until you get. This problem is only because of anchorPoint and add this line before rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue as you. My problem was that I was doing the rotation in the **viewDidLoad**.

Try to do it in the **viewDidAppear**, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the UIImageView contentMode is set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or other scaled aspect, the rotation will cause the image to disappear.

Changing the contentMode to UIViewContentModeCenter should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I had the same issue. I did everything in a dispatch once in viewDidLayoutSubViews..... It's bizarre that CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); and CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); works but not this. If anyone knows if this is a reported issue I would love the link.